# Access nested containers in a TTree with PyROOT

Tags: python, root-framework

Within PyROOT, it's easy enough to read in values from a tree, i.e. to print the leaf `val`:

```
file = TFile('file.root')
tree = file.Get('tree')
for entry in tree: 
    print entry.val
```

Also easy to read values out of a stl `vector<float>`, `vec`:

```
for entry in tree: 
    print entry.vec[1]
```

But what about nested vectors, i.e. `nested` of type `vector<vector<float> >`? Running

```
for entry in tree: 
    print entry.nested[0][0]
```

will throw a `TypeError: 'vector<vector<float> >' object is unindexable`.

What is the best way to deal with this? (better if it doesn't require loading in a ROOT dictionary)

Comment: you can try this: http://steve.cooleysekula.net/goingupalleys/2011/07/29/python-and-root-tricks-vectors-of-vectors/

Comment: nice intro, new kind of "answering a question with a question"

Answer (score 3):

This works for me using indexing in python.

```
    >>>from ROOT import *
    >>>vec1 = std.vector('double')()
    >>>vec2 = std.vector('double')()
    >>>vec_vec = std.vector(std.vector('double'))()

    >>>for i in range(3):
    >>>   vec1.push_back(i)
    >>>for i in range(5):
    >>>   vec2.push_back(i)
    >>>vec_vec.push_back(vec1)
    >>>vec_vec.push_back(vec2)

    >>>len(vec_vec)
    2
    >>>len(vec_vec[0])
    3
    >>>len(vec_vec[1])
    5
    >>>vec_vec[1][2]
    2.0
```

In your example the error says:

```
    TypeError: 'vector<vector<float> >' object is unindexable
```

After calling the constructor std.vector(type)() you have different types that indicate that an allocator for memory space is working.

```
    >>>type(vec1)
    <class 'ROOT.vector<double,allocator<double> >'>
    >>>type(vec_vec)
    <class 'ROOT.vector<vector<double,allocator<double> >,allocator<vector<double,allocator<double> > > >'>
```

To import such vectors from a TTree use setBranchAddress like in this example:

```
    >>>tree = file.Get('tree')
    >>>tree.SetBranchAddress("nested",vec_vec)
    >>>N = tree.GetEntries()
    >>>for i in range(N):
    >>>    vec_vec.clear()
    >>>    tree.GetEntry(i)
    >>>    print vec_vec[0][0]
```

Also note that this may be significantly faster after using

```
   >>>tree.setBranchStatus('*',0)
   >>>tree.setBranchStatus('nested',1)
```

Comment: your line `>>>vec_vec = std.vector(std.vector('double'))()` makes my interpretor print `Segmentation fault` and quit. I'm using python 2.6 and ROOT 5.28, for comparison.

Comment: Tested it again, works with python 2.7.2+ and ROOT 5.31 on Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: this needs to run on SLC5 and python 2.6 (sadly). Also, since this solution requires me to declare the variable outside the loop, set the branch address, and then call `GetEntry` for each loop iteration, I'm not sure if it's cleaner than using a dictionary (as suggested in the link provided by @wiso).

Comment: Your line "for entry in tree" calls tree.GetEntry N times anyway, so that's just syntax.Setting the branchadress should speed things up, since there is memory space already allocated for the values fetched from the tree. The link @wiso provides does very much the same, like what i suggested, just in C++ not in python. This has nothing to do with python version i think. Could be thath you can get the std.vector class linked by installing the recent ROOT version from source and linking the build against python. Like described here: http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/installing-root-source